# CollectionType adds 2 rows on + click sonata

Tags: sonata-admin

I have extended sonata edit page with this:

```
{% extends '@SonataAdmin/CRUD/base_edit.html.twig' %}

{% block javascripts %}
    {{ parent() }}
    {{ encore_entry_script_tags('select2', null, 'admin') }}
{% endblock %}
```

But now when I click + button nera "Product option group codes" , it adds 2 rows.

[image]

If I remove

```
{{ encore_entry_script_tags('select2', null, 'admin') }}
```

then it works ok - adds just one row on + click.

I have commented all code in selec2.js file, to make sure it is not causing something but still nothing changes.

If I remove

```
parent()
```

Then "Product option group codes" js stops working.

How to debug? Where could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Noticed that this js was not by sonata, but in our script. And when adding

```
{{ encore_entry_script_tags('select2', null, 'admin') }}
```

it calls document ready in another JS 2nd time, which setups + sign listener. So 2 listeners are set up.

To avoid this, instead of encore function, using script tag solved the problem. Also changed file name which I include.

```
{% extends '@SonataAdmin/CRUD/base_edit.html.twig' %}

{% block javascripts %}
    {{ parent() }}

    <script src="{{ asset('build/admin/admin-state-disaster-scenario.js', 'admin') }}"></script>
{% endblock %}
```